Flask server says 404 error. Even when the routes are CLEARLY defined
Flask API Route Returns 404 Error
API Route Definition:
I've defined an API route /api/recommendations/<user_id> in my Flask application to retrieve meditation recommendations for a specific user.
The route handler function get_user_data(user_id) queries Firestore to fetch user statistics and form data, calculates user embeddings using spaCy, and computes similarities with meditation embeddings.
When the data is ready, the function returns a JSON response with the user ID and recommended meditation names.
I'm developing a Flask application with an API route to retrieve recommendations based on user data stored in Firestore. However, when I try to access the API route, I receive a 404 error indicating that the route is not found. Here's my Flask application code:
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
import numpy as np
import spacy

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

cred = credentials.Certificate(r"firebase/connection")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")

@app.route('/api/recommendations/<user_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_user_data(user_id):
    try:
        stats_ref = db.collection('stats').document(user_id)
        stats_data = stats_ref.get().to_dict()
        minutes = stats_data.get('Minutes', 0)
        sessions = stats_data.get('Sessions', 0)
        forms_ref = db.collection('form').document(user_id)
        forms_data = forms_ref.get().to_dict()
        answers = forms_data.get('answers', [])

        user_query = f"Minutes: {minutes} Sessions: {sessions} {' '.join(answers)}"
        user_embedding = nlp(user_query).vector

        meditations_ref = db.collection('meditations')
        meditations_data = [doc.to_dict() for doc in meditations_ref.stream()]

        meditations_embeddings = []
        for meditation in meditations_data:
            meditation_text = f"{meditation['name']} {meditation['tag']} {meditation['duration']}"
            meditation_embedding = nlp(meditation_text).vector
            meditations_embeddings.append(meditation_embedding)

        meditations_embeddings = np.array(meditations_embeddings)

        similarities = np.dot(meditations_embeddings, user_embedding) / (
                np.linalg.norm(meditations_embeddings, axis=1) * np.linalg.norm(user_embedding))

        top_indices = np.argsort(similarities)[::-1][:3]
        similar_meditations_names = [meditations_data[i]['name'] for i in top_indices]

        return jsonify({
            'user_id': user_id,
            'similar_meditations_names': similar_meditations_names
        })

    except Exception as e:
        app.logger.error(f"Error occurred: {str(e)}")
        return jsonify({'error': 'Internal Server Error'}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.config['ENV'] = 'development'
        app.config['DEBUG'] = True

        app.run(host='localhost', port=8080)


I've tried accessing the API route (/api/recommendations/<user_id>) using Postman, from the frontend, and manually, but I consistently receive a 404 error. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

Are you sure you used correct method to call (GET in your case) the API? I should be working. Are you able to get the \\ route?

When entering the URL in Postman, did you include the host and port?
ex) http://localhost:8080/api/recommendations/<user_id>

Missing hostname or port result in site can't be reached error, not result in HTTP 404
